# Issues handling with dates in different systems at VBA

Tags: vba, date

I wonder if anyone can give me some guidance concerning dates.

I am working on this form that contains a date in a textbox and spinbutton that adds/subtracts a day from this date.

In my system, the current date format is dd/mm/yyyy. But I noticed that if user has another format, the spin button will not work properly.

My questions

1. Is there any windows api that gets user`s system date format? What about a windows api that changes this format?
2. What is the best way to work on a solution for dates (I have been having lots of troubles when it comes to dates, not just in this application)
3. Any advices regarding dates at different systems will be appreciated.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

If you are using macro,

Use "Cdate" to convert values to date. it will convert  different date formats into similar date format. 
It can be used for comparing two different format dates
For Example.

```
Function MyDate(rng As String)
  MyDate = CDate(rng)
End Function
```

In excel formula, You can use "Datevalue" formula to convert different date formats to similar date format.

Use the below link to read it more

http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1143-excel-convert-number-to-date.html